# Trouble to import csv file

Tags: r, csv, import, read.csv

I want to import a csv file in R, but can not figure out the structure of the file. Variables are not seperated by columns, but by commas. Data are separated by simple comma or double commas.

[image]

I tried:

```
data<- read.csv("file.source", header= T)
```

then

```
data<- read.csv("file.source", header= T,na.string=c(""," "))
```

I only have 1,203 rows while I am supposed to have more than 50,000 rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
data<- read.csv("file.source", header= T, sep = ",")
```

or

```
data<- read.csv("file.source", header= T, sep = ";")
```

Comment: yes I explicitly tried ```sep= ","```  then ```sep= ";"``` even if default separtors are ```","``` in ```read.csv``` and ```";"``` with``` read.csv2```

Comment: Try put .csv after "file.source" `file.source.csv`